# Strategy for model entities in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

A part of the web application I'm building is user administration. Thus I have the need for a user entity. There are several use cases that involves a user, for example:

- Show a list of users
- Show a single user
- Edit user contact information
- Edit user login information (username and password)
- Create a new user

Most of these needs access to the same properties so it would be nice to use the same entity for all cases. Then, if I use for example DisplayName attribute, all places would use the same display name:

```
[Display(Name = "Username")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

When editing a user, I want to use validation attributes as well:

```
[Display(Name = "Username")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Username must be provided.")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

The problem occurs when I have a view where some properties are edited, but not all. In the "Edit user contact information" use case, some things are available for editing (e.g. PhoneNumber) but some are not (e.g. Username). But if I use the same entity, all properties with validation attributes will be validated.

I've found some [solutions to the validation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604049/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-exclude-some-field-validation-in-tryupdatemodel) here on StackOverflow, but I'm wondering if there are any "best practises" when creating entities and viewmodels?

I prefer to re-use as much as possible to make sure that for example display names and validation is consistent throughout the application. But often that leads to problems such as the one described above or complex inheritance hiearchies.

Should I have:

- Several similiar (but not identical) entities?
- Several similiar (but not identical) viewmodels?
- One entity + workarounds for problems such as the validation problem?
- ...

**Any suggestions? How do you do this yourself?**

I should note that I often show more information than just what is being edited. For example, when editing contact information I will have inputs for some properties (e.g. PhoneNumber and EmailAddress) but still show other properties as information to the user (e.g. Username).

*(I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 if it matters)*

Comment: Personally, I use the IValidatableObject interface on the model that I'm passing to the view, this may be the simple raw entity, or a more complex view model that's based on an entity/entities.  If I'm implementing the interface on an EF/L2S entity object I use a partial class to get around the codegen.  Using IValidatableObject, you could have a switch to turn certain validation rules on or off depending on the situation.  Alternatively, you could just re-implement the interface or whatever validation method you wish on a stripped down view model.

Answer (score 1):

If validation is your only issue, i would suggest using fluentvalidation (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com). 
That way you can set the validation rules per scenarion (per action).

I would use separate viewmodels for each scenario, and the utilize the RuleSets feature in fluentmvc so I wouldn't violate DRY.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a [view model per view](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/) approach.  While this does seem like extra work I believe it makes your controllers & views more succinct and understandable.  It's very clear what your intent is in each case and you still get strong typing.

It also solves another issue potentially with [mass assignment vulnerability](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) (as would the bind include/exclude).

Last using this technique doesn't require any extra coding bits that some might consider magic or at least will require more careful reading of the code to understand what this view is doing with the model versus this other view, versus this other view since all three use the same model a slightly different way.

Comment: With this approach I guess I would put all display attributes and validation attributes in the viewmodel. Wouldn't that mean that they are duplicated, or is there some way to get around that? I mean, I will have several viewmodels displaying the same data (and also, although less common, several viewmodels validating the same data).

Comment: In a case where a viewmodel can be used the same for several views I would use it over again and if changes are needed over the future where a view needs to deviate then I would create a new VM for it.

Comment: As for duplicates in part, yes this may seem like extra work but we are talking most of the time about attributes and shouldn't cause too much headache.  There are ways to reduce this by creating an inherited VM where the parent would have the commonly shared properties across your VMs and then have each VM inherit from it and then add their own. For example if Name was always used on 5 VMs then create a parent VM with name only and it's validations and then for each child inherit it and add their unique items.

Answer (score 0):

To add variable validation logic to your model, you could implement IValidatableObject:

```
public class VariableValidationEntity : IValidatableObject
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool ValidateMe { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ValidateMe)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Username Required", new[] { "UserName" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then specify your validation logic depending on the environment that you're using your model in.

Alternatively, you could have a view model per use case, and even derive the validated model from your base model:

```
public class NonValidatedEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class ValidatedEntity : NonValidatedEntity, IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Username Required", new[] { "UserName" });
        }
    }
}
```

The latter option would be cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Nice solution, but I really like the validation attributes. Mostly because it makes it easy to have client-side validation. Is there an elegant solution for client-side validation using this technique too?