# Use TryUpdateModel to bind partially supplied values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I need to update an object from information that was posted to the action. As long as the information is in the page this works fine. However, it requires that I put information into hidden fields if I don't want the modelstate to complain.

As an example, lets say I am using the class below as the model:

```
public class Client
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

If I don't want the user to edit the name, I need to include it in a hidden field so that it get bound to the model and the validation passes.

The problem I have is that is obviously not secure if used with more sensitive information. So I tried this:

```
public virtual ActionResult Save(Client model, int clientId)
    {
        var client = datasource.LoadEntity(adapter, clientId); // clientId is passed as a querystring to the action

        if (!TryUpdateModel(client))
            return new RedirectResult('The edit page URL');
    }
```

The problem is that the modelstate still complains about the "Name" value not being available even though it was loaded to the client object from the database.

Obviously I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

Comment: If you are concerned about security, you really should be using SSL to secure communication between the client and the server. The reason for the framework complaining is that validation occurs just prior to the action being executed during model binding, what you are attempting to do is at a point too late.

Comment: @ChrisHardie I'm actually using the solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604049/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-exclude-some-field-validation-in-tryupdatemodel?rq=1 which is doing exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The view model is just for information coming from the client.

So you have to remove the `Name` property and get it from somewhere else.

If this is a view model also used by the administrator for example (who is able to enter/change the name) then the best would be a derived view model like this:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClientWithName : Client
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470377%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) `TryUpdateModel(TModel, string\[\])`; if my understanding is correct, this should allow to specify the property to include in the update, like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult Save(Client model, int clientId)
{
    var client = datasource.LoadEntity(adapter, clientId);

    if (!TryUpdateModel(client, new string[] { "Email" }))
        return new RedirectResult('The edit page URL');
}
```

I never tried it though, can you let us know if it works as expected?

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem that the modelstate is still not valid as it seems to be set before entering the action.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone with the solution outlined here: [Asp.net MVC 3 Validation exclude some field validation in TryUpdateModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604049/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-exclude-some-field-validation-in-tryupdatemodel?rq=1)

Essentially, it removes the validation from the Modelstate if those fields aren't present which works for me as those values are retrieved from the database.