# ActionFilter to exclude properties validated in Edit method not working ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, action-filter

I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC. I'm referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604049/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-exclude-some-field-validation-in-tryupdatemodel) answer to solve my problem. I researched a lot for hours to find a way to exclude properties from edit action. 
I used data binging but with no luck, i used a view model to include only the fields need to be modified, which worked but I'm not 100% happy because I'm looking for an easier and a reusable approach. I tried using TryUpdateModel() but i don't completely understand how to implement it.

Above link looks like a perfect solution but unfortunately i still got the same validation error `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedBy', table 'xxx'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.` 
Any idea why? help greatly appreciated.

**Edit** : let me clearly state what i want here again. I want 'CreatedBy' in my model that's why i have a property for that. I cant just remove it. I don't want to use a hidden field in my view to pass the value so it won't be null. I just want a proper and easy way to exclude properties from Edit. Is there a better solution for this except using viewmodels?

Details:
`CreatedBy` is a required field which is populated on create action.
My view contains editors for all the fields in my model except `CreatedBy`

My controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateOnlyIncomingValuesAttribute]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "CreatedBy")] Request model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
            var emp = db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ApplicationUser == db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(currentUser)));

            if (emp != null)
            {
                model.ModifiedBy      = emp.NIC;
                model.ModifiedDate    = DateTime.Now;
                db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
         // some code
      }
    }
```

My action filter

```
public class ValidateOnlyIncomingValuesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            var valueProvider = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider;

            var keysWithNoIncomingValue = modelState.Keys.Where(x => !valueProvider.ContainsPrefix(x));
            foreach (var key in keysWithNoIncomingValue)
                modelState[key].Errors.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As manish indicated, your error has nothing to do with validation

**Option 1**

Render a hidden input for `CreatedBy` so it posts back and remove the `[Bind(Exclude = "CreatedBy")]` from your method. The value will be updated in the database, but with the same value you started with so its unchanged

**Option 2**

Depending on which version of EF you can use a 'blacklist' approach (for EF5+ I think)

```
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

or a 'whitelist' approach where you need to set `EntityState.Modified;` for each property except `CreatedBy`

```
// db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified; // do do this
db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.SomeProperty).State = EntityState.Modified;
// Repeat for all properties except `CreatedBy`
```

Comment: now i got this strange error `Member 'IsModified' cannot be called for property 'CreatedBy' because the entity of type 'Request' does not exist in the context` maybe because Request object passed is not same as existing one in the context?

Comment: Has the model been detached? Try `db.Requests.Attach(model);` (before modifying state)

Comment: I had the same problem in that I had an xml property I didn't want to bind and update (the server rejected it!), yet it HAD to be in the model else it would be set to null. Using `db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;` worked perfectly! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not MVC validation error. it is exception you getting. you are trying to add null value for CreatedBy column which is actually non-nullable.

Make CreatedBy column nullable or assign value for it from controller.

Comment: doh! yeah it is! is there a way to use actionfilters to achieve this anyway? i don't want to make it nullable or assign any value to it. Need to exclude values.

Comment: i don't understand. you don't want to assign any value to it and also want non-nullable. how is it possible? You must assign value if you want non-nullable column

Comment: did u read my question completely? It already has a value. CreatedBy field is populated when the record is added to the database. This is edit action. So i don't want CreatedBy value here anymore.

Comment: Can you just exclude the CreatedBy field from the Model? then it won't try to validate in your Edit() method

Comment: @guitarlass, did u read manish's question completely? Its not a validation issue - the error is raised when you update the database. Add a hidden input to view for `Created` so its posts back the original and remove `[Bind(Exclude = "CreatedBy")]`

Comment: yes i did. i also tired your method. that was what implemented first. but that way method is passing CreatedBy value and eventually it get edited. I just want to prevent it from being edited. it's there any way i could achieve this???

Comment: Are your users really hacking **hidden** inputs and editing them? But see answer

Comment: nope, i meant the value is posted to the update query. i want to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

//Update

Understanding your decision not to use ViewModels, even that for me that's not for the sake of reusability, I think there are two things clear here.

A-> You are not having a validation error

B-> [Bind(Exclude = "CreatedBy")] works fine

So per A, I would even remove that filter. You're sure that that CreatedBy property has been created according to the validation rules so you don't need to skip validation in that given you are expecting that value again. And if a dodgy user has tried to edit it that validation at least doesn't make you any harm.

B-> You have that model with that property as null so as stated in a few comments you should be populating it before updating the entitiy in the db. But you don't trust the hidden input fields as the value for that property.
I guess you're using an ORM and I don't know if any allows you to update partially the way you're trying to do i.e. just passing a model with some null property in a non-nullable one and expecting it to infere that it has to get the previous value for that property. I hardly doubt it. So the options here aren't that many:

You should fetch the model from the database, update individually the subset of properties you want to and save it again. So that means basically you could even get rid of The Bind(Exclude... bit, you won't give and editor field for that in the view and in case somebody edit it and won't use that update.

I wouldn't even think of doing that in a so-called reusable filter as the trip to the db would be per case.

I can think of some other convoluted ways of doing it. But don't worth mentioning them, actually this leaves a question open to me, are you exposing theId for that entity? because you are opening a vulnerability there, they can edit another one and maybe that's not what you want. and so on... I'm not sure if you came across [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/12/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)in your research.

To me, I insist you shouldn't be messing around like this: ViewModels is the answer

//End of update

I would create a ViewModel with the properties you want in it (i.e. leaving out the CreatedBy), use that for what it is, the model for the view and don't use the domain entity model for that.

Something like this

```
public ActionResult Edit(RequestViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
        var emp = db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ApplicationUser == db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(currentUser)));

        if (emp != null)
        {
            var domainModel = GetRequestById(model.Id) //Or whatever method you have for this

            //Update whatever you want in domainModel, basically all apart from CreatedBy from the model
            domainModel.Property1 = model.Property1 

            //Save the updated domainModel
        }
     // some code
  }
}
```

Being your RequestViewModel something like this

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    Guid Id {get; set;} //Or whatever Id you use (int...)

    //Rest of the properties you really want them to be able to edit

 }
```

This way you could even add the CreatedBy to the viewmodel if you for example wanted to display it in your edit view but you won't update it in the post back if you wanted (and therefore use it as viewmodel for the create action as well, although many times I don't mind and actually prefer to create a edit viwmodel and a create viewmodel if they differ)

Comment: thanks but, as i have mentioned in my question, I implemented a viewmodel and it works. I'm just not happy with that solution and looking for a different one.