# How to remove property of model from client side validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

In my model I have a class `User` where the variable `Password` is a required property.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailValidator(ErrorMessage = "Email entered is not valid")]
    [Display(Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

My `EditUser` view:

```
@model User
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create User" />
    </p>

}
```

In the view I have excluded the field 'password' in user edit, and in order to validate the model in the controller I have used `[Bind(Exclude="Password")]`, but it doesn't work, so I have used `ModelState.Remove("Password");` but it validates on server side. If I am using all the fields (including `Password`) it validates on client side.
How can I validate this on the client side (when excluding one field)?

Comment: Are you sure you have included `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`` at your page?

Comment: I read your question twice but it still don't understand it. Could you please reformat it to make more than one sentence?

Comment: What do you mean _"excluded the field 'password' in user edit"_ If you don't have a control for `Password` then how could it be validated on the client (it does not exist).

Comment: Show the view and the controller so we can understand what your trying to do.

Comment: What do you want to validate? Be specific.

Comment: what you want say clear in your question... you have no control on password and not required then why you keep in your view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net MVC 3 Validation exclude some field validation in TryUpdateModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604049/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-exclude-some-field-validation-in-tryupdatemodel)

Comment: Firstly a `Password` property does not belong in a `User` class (its used for login) so you should remove it. But what do you mean _"how can i validate this in client side?"_? Validate what? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have a create user page where a user can enter password when creating a new user. so I have used 'password' field in user class. and validate on client side means validate the fields with out a postback

Comment: You need to rethink what you are doing. You should have a login page and a register page where you enter the username and password, and a separate page for editing user information - 3 completely different actions, 3 completely different models. But in any case what are you expecting to validate on the client. You don't generate a control for `Password` so what possible validation could there be! Your not making any sense - what validation are your expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I presume your model is model from the database. Sometimes data models do not work for views. To make it work I recommend you to introduce different ViewModel class that addresses all the view aspects. Most likely it will be your User model but without password field:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailValidator(ErrorMessage = "Email entered is not valid")]
    [Display(Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

So instead of using your "data" model, you use view model and then map it in controller to a data model.